# yarn not installing packages from workspace but instead tries pulling down from npmjs with turborepo

Tags: yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces, turbo, turborepo

Version:

`"packageManager": "yarn@1.22.19"`

I have based my project off of the `npx create-turbo@latest` command.

I have `eslint-config-custom` and `tsconfig` projects inside my /packages folder which I reference in my three nodejs apps with:

```
 "tsconfig": "workspace:*",
 "eslint-config-custom": "workspace:*",
```

and in my root package.json workspaces are defined:

```
  "workspaces": [
    "apps/*",
    "packages/*"
  ],
```

Unfortunately, when I run `yarn` or `yarn install` in the root folder, yarn pops up telling me to select a matching version:

```
yarn install v1.22.19
info No lockfile found.
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
Couldn't find any versions for "eslint-config-custom" that matches "workspace:0.0.0"
? Please choose a version of "eslint-config-custom" from this list: (Use arrow keys)
> 0.0.0
```

Same for the `tsconfig` dependency, then it only lists versions available for the packages with the same name on the main `npmjs.com` registry.

How do I get yarn to use the dependency from a workspace?

Additionally, how could I deal with them with a scope, and instead of `tsconfig` to install from `@myOrg/tsconfig`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. In your app's `package.json`, try these

```
 "tsconfig": "*",
 "eslint-config-custom": "*",
```

In `pnpm`, packages are installed by `workspaces:*`, but in other package managers you can do it by only `*`. We are using `yarn`, so `*` would be work.

Take a look at [Offical Example](https://github.com/vercel/turborepo/tree/main/examples/basic).

---

2. If I understand it correctly, answer for the additional question is posted in github
   [discussions](https://github.com/vercel/turborepo/discussions/315).

In `package.json`'s  `name` field, include your organization scope.
(`@myOrg/package-name`)
But don't change your folder's structure or it's name.

Comment: That was it, my initial project was made with pnpm and had to switch to yarn because of the prune command not working, but then switched back.